# Terminal 3 Dubai Airport meeting point

Tags: transit, dxb

I am meeting a colleague in Terminal 3. She is flying in from Glasgow and I am flying in from Newcastle. We are both then getting the same flight to Manila. As the terminal is so large and neither of us have been there before where would be a good place to arrange to meet? I have a 3 hours stop over and she has 2 hours.

Comment: If you’re flying with Emirates, this might help https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/dubai-international-airport/emirates-terminal-3/finding-your-way.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Anything under 2 hours in Dubai airport is usually considered a short connection, considering the size of the airport.

The first suggestion that comes to mind is your departure gate. Therefore, both of you will have enough time to reach your flight and most certainly both of you will find it.